# How to notify the build status to bitbucket UI when there is no pull request create and merge?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, bcbsn

Am new to Jenkins. I found a plugin to notify the each commit status in bit bucket UI(Bit bucket Cloud Build Status Notifier Plugin) and am very much confused about notifying the build status.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin

Am doing commit continuously in development branch and i have registered the oauth credentials as described in above link with Jenkins job.  After the Jenkins job run, i could not see the build status in bit bucket cloud UI.

Could anyone please suggest me whether this plugin update the commit status from pull request page to development branch while merge? Or This plugin can pass the direct build status to development branch when commit done and Jenkins job ran.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you using a Pipeline job? A multibranch project? Or a Freestyle?

Comment: Am using FreeStyle project

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin is configured properly you should be able to see the build status posted by the plugin in commit history of your development branch within Bitbucket Cloud. The build status is set for a given commit sha1, that means that it doesn't care if it's a pull request or not since the commit sha1 doesn't change.

If the build status is not shown in Bibucket Clould UI, I guess your problem is related to the plugin or Jenkins configuration. Take a look to the Jenkins log file for more information in order to be able to guide you to solve the problem.